# Как сохранять в БД название картинки (Spring MVC + MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Я написал проект где можно добавлять студенту фио и фотку через  спринг в базу данных. Я реализовал но только он хранит его как то не так, какие то символы в таблице avatar.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой контроллер

```
package fallen.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

    private final static File UPLOAD_FOLDER = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/avatars/");

    static {
        if (!UPLOAD_FOLDER.exists()) {
            UPLOAD_FOLDER.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello(HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
        return mv;
    }

    // Get All Users
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setSurname(surname);
            student.setSurname(name);
            student.setAvatar(file.getBytes());
            studentService.saveStudent(student);
        }

        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void image(@RequestParam String url, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(url);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEditedUser(@ModelAttribute Student student, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(result.toString());
            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }
        boolean isSaved = studentService.saveStudent(student);
        if (!isSaved) {

            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        boolean isDeleted = studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        System.out.println("Удаление студента: " + isDeleted);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");
        return mv;

    }

}
```

Student (entity)

```
package fallen.java.schoolmaven.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    @Lob
    private byte[] avatar;
    @Transient
    private String base64Image;



    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }


    public String getBase64Image() {
        if(avatar == null) return "";
        String base64Image = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(this.avatar);
        return base64Image;
    }


    public byte[] getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(byte[] avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    @Override

    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Вы уже задавали такой же вопрос несколько дней назад

Comment: Нет не задавал, там был вопрос как добавить фотку студенту. Я уже реализовал его, теперь нужно чтобы он хранил его  название и чтобы у каждой добавленной фотки студенту был id

Comment: и в чем проблема? Вы же его кодируете тут `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(this.avatar)` по этому там так

Comment: @damagedd аа, ну сори

Comment: А почему вы в байтах храните, а не в виде пути к файлу на сервере?